# Excel - use one value if another cell IF equals true

Tags: excel

So, a bit of background, I have a workbook with 2 sheets. One has a list of names and a couple of formulas which count those up.

I would like to use the "total" figure (which is already calculated on sheet 1) in sheet 2.

I would like to use it as follows:-

I have a cell where user can enter 1 or 2. 2 is TRUE and 1 is FALSE
Then if the result is true I would like another cell to use the value from the Total figure on sheet one (Let's say its cell L6) or if it's false to use a user entered figure in say M6 of sheet2.

I have the total figure calculated on Sheet one and I have a formula output to cell N4 (hidden) which has the TRUE or FALSE result.

I have looked at Dynamic named ranges and cell references but I am not sure if this is what I need?

Comment: Post a sample of your sheet, otherwise it is difficult to glean into your description.Also include exactly what you tried and what did not work

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly your question, you can use:

Lets say A1 could be TRUE or FALSE
Total:

```
IF(A1=1;your code;IF(A1=2;your code;your code))
```

or if there is only one value to change in the Total formula, you can replace it with IF statement. It would be easier to answer, if we could see your formulas.